# Set Limit For Value, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, max

I have the following code:

```
float valueCalculated = (val1 / val2) * 100;
```

What I want to be able to do is to cap the maximum value of valueCalculated to 100.

I believe I could do this using some sort of if statement, but this would mean many more lines of code. Edit// This is not the case, see the answers below.

Thanks,

Stu

Comment: What are the ranges of val1 and val2?

Comment: Apologies, I neglected to mention valueCalculated will not be negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean "many more lines of code" like this?

```
if (valueCalculated > 100) { valueCalculated = 100; }
```

Comment: That is brilliant, so simple too! I am just learning and no matter how I searched I could not find this! Thanks to all.

Comment: This awesomeness is awesome! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
float valueCalculated = MIN((val1 / val2) * 100, 100);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Simple, clever - wish I had thought of it myself...

Answer (score 0):

```
float valueCalculated = (float temp = (val1 / val2) * 100) > 100 ? 100 : temp;
```

but I guess a function would be better, you can do with function or a simple macro:

```
#define MAX(m, toset) toset = (toset > m ? m : toset)

MAX(100, valueCalculated);
```

I guess I understood better your question:

```
valueCalculated = MAX(100, (val1 / val2) * 100);
```

where

```
#define MAX(max, val) (((val) > (max)) ? (max) : (val))
```

hope it helps,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question then...

```
float valueCalculated = fminf((val1 / val2) * 100, 100);
```

...should do what your asking.

However, are you worried about negative values, i.e. could val1 or val2 be negative and do you want to limit possible values for valueCalculated to 0-100?. If so then you might want...

```
float valueCalculated = fmaxf(fminf((val1 / val2) * 100, 100), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
float valueCalculated = ((val1 / val2) * 100 < 100) ? (val1 / val2) * 100 : 100
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an iphone dev, but isn't modulo what you're looking for?

```
float valueCalculated = ((val1 / val2) * 100) % 101;
```

?

Comment: modulo would seem to work well, but if the value comes to "101", then "% 101" would make it 0.  I think he just wants it capped at 100.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to limit a calculated value to 0 to 100 by "weighting" it, you would divide that value by the maximum that it could be and then multiply by 100. This assumes the value isn't negative.